# How to set Flutter build android aar version?

Tags: android, flutter, aar

when I use flutter build aar, it always build version 1.0, for example: flutter_release-1.0.aar. how could I update this version to flutter_release-2.0.aar?

```
version: 2.0.0+3
```

I change pubspec.yaml files version as above, it still useless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can do that in command:

```
flutter build aar --build-number=2.0
```

Incase you want to generate only release aar then try this

```
flutter build aar --no-debug --no-profile --build-number=2.0
```

for more info on this command try this

```
flutter build aar -h
```

Comment: Hi friend, are you facing with problem connect the internet with the aar release mode. 
I can't connect internet with aar release , but debug working normal. The internet permission already added.